# Imitating outlook scheduler using winform

Tags: winforms, outlook, scheduler

what is the best way to mimic the scheduler screen of the outlook 2003. Currently I'm using DataGridView with customized DataGridViewCell and DataGridViewColumn as sugeested in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fb61s43.aspx). I think DataGridView is heavy. Is there a better approach which is light weight and less CPU consuming to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most everything in Outlook is VERY complex, so if you are looking to get really close, I would look at third-party controls for Windows Forms (Infragistics, Telerik, ComponentSource to name a few sites).

If you're just looking for concept on the UI, check out this sample...

http://rjmooney.blogspot.com/2004/01/outlook-style-calendar-month-control.html